# Why's the Phillip's curve steep when the the short-run aggregate supply curve is steep?

Tags: macroeconomics

Why's the Phillip's curve steep when the the short-run aggregate supply (SRAS) curve is steep?

The Phillip's curve is given by $\pi = \pi^e - \alpha (u - u^{*})$ and he SRAS curve is given by $Y - Y^{*} = \beta (P - P^e)$ where the variables $\pi, \pi^e, u, u^{*}, Y, Y^{*}, P, P^e$ denote inflation, expected inflation, unemployment, the natural rate of unemployment, output, natural rate of output, price level and the expected price level, in that order.

I understand that a small change in output corresponds to a small change in unemployment. But a small change in output corresponds to a relatively larger change in the price level (due to steep SRAS) or inflation. In the end, a relatively large change in inflation will correspond to a small change in inflation, and so we get a steep Phillip's curve.

Can I get the same explanation using the two equations I mentioned?